# Binding Data to a TextBlock using Domain Data Source

Tags: silverlight, binding, stackpanel

I have a map with hotspots for each state (done in Expression Blend).  I capture each MouseEnter of the state (1 thru 50).  I pass that into my Domain Data Source:

```
    Dim activebox As Path = TryCast(sender, Path)
    activebox.Fill = mouseOverColor
    Dim StateID As Integer = CInt(Right(activebox.Name, 2))

     Dim _StateContext As New StateContext
     myDataGrid.ItemsSource = _StateContext.States
    _StateContext.Load(_StateContext.GetStateByStateIDQuery(StateID.Text))
```

The above works fine for a datagrid, listbox and even a dataform.

But I created a popup with a stackpanel that has textblocks.

```
    popupStatesBox.DataContext = ??????????????
    popupStatesBox.IsOpen = True   'popup does open but has no data
```

-- popupStatesBox.xaml

> ```
>   <Popup x:Name="popupStatsBox" Margin="8,35,0,8" DataContext="{Binding}" 
>        IsOpen="false" Width="268" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
>       <StackPanel x:Name="Layout" Background="Black">
>  <TextBlock x:Name="tbState" Text="{Binding StateName />
>  <TextBlock x:Name="tbAbbrev" Text="{Binding Abbreviation}"  />   
>       </StackPanel>
>   </Popup>
> ```

How do I get the textblocks to display the values from the _StateContext.
StackPanel has DataContext but no ItemsSource. What am I missing?

Comment: What does your working example look like?  I'm struggling to see how you would use a ListBox in place of your popup.

Comment: Surely the states collection already has the state data you need?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've already loaded the States collection in the context then this is probably the sort of thing you are after:-

```
 popupStatsBox.DataContext = _StateContext.States.FirstOrDefault(Function(s) s.StateID = StateID)
```

Note that encoding data into element names is not a good practice, look into creating an attached property and store the state ID as an attached property of each Path.

To be honest I would be tempted to create a custom control derived from a `Selector` to create a StatesSelector control.

You would bind the ItemsSource property to your States collection.  As the mouse moves 
about assign the appropiate item from the ItemsSource to the`SelectedItem` property.

However that may be taking things a little too far.

Comment: Thanks Anthony. It's working almost as I expect. There seems to be a delay on the loading of the data on mouseenter. When I mouseenter an image I pass a numeric value, the popup appears without data.
If I mouseout then mouseenter again, the popup appears with data. BTW, you mentioned "To be honest I would be tempted to create a custom control derived from a Selector to create a StatesSelector control." Where can I find more info on that '...custom control....'?